# tmux powerline keeps adding status bars

Tags: command-line, tmux

I installed powerline and it works fine in the normal terminal.
But when I open tmux it keeps adding status-bars at the bottom of the window every 2 or 3 seconds. 
My `.tmux.conf` only contains `source path/to/powerline/tmux/binding`.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

This problem is described [on GitHub here](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1652)

For some reason, deleting the watch character in `powerline.json` didn't work for me, but deleting the `"name": "time"` line in the `.../tmux/default.json` file removed the clock and fixed the problem.